# Getting issue when trying to set the image source from API JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

Getting issue when trying to set the image SCR from Youtube API

**Jquery**

```
  $("#imgscr").attr("src", data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
```

**html code**

```
    <img src="#" id="duckBhaiimg" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

- So what I want to achieve is to get the URL from the JSON and set to
  the #Imgscr. If you see in the JSON we have 'thumbnails' object in that object we have 'URL' I want its value to be set on #Imgscr.
- And also want to get data from localized object

**Json**

```
 "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#channel",
       "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/8ENLhz-4x-I1Wub-o7UpmXo-rcY\"",
       "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
       "snippet": {
        "title": "PewDiePie",
        "description": "I make videos.",
        "customUrl": "PewDiePie",
        "publishedAt": "2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 88,
          "height": 88
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 240,
          "height": 240
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 800,
          "height": 800
         }
        },
        "localized": {
         "title": "PewDiePie",
         "description": "I make videos."
        },
        "country": "US"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this image `<img src="#" id="duckBhaiimg" alt="Alternate Text" />` with id of `duckBhaiimg` and in your `jQuery` you are looking for id `imgscr`.

change your code to the following.

```
<img src="#" id="imgscr" alt="Alternate Text" />
$("#imgscr").attr("src", data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
```

```js
const data = { items: [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#channel",
       "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/8ENLhz-4x-I1Wub-o7UpmXo-rcY\"",
       "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
       "snippet": {
        "title": "PewDiePie",
        "description": "I make videos.",
        "customUrl": "PewDiePie",
        "publishedAt": "2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z",
        "thumbnails": {
         "default": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 88,
          "height": 88
         },
         "medium": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 240,
          "height": 240
         },
         "high": {
          "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAPBVgUYqlLw9SvJyKAVWmgkQ2-KrkgSv4_5A=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
          "width": 800,
          "height": 800
         }
        },
        "localized": {
         "title": "PewDiePie",
         "description": "I make videos."
        },
        "country": "US"
       }
      }
     ]
             }
$("#imgscr").attr("src", data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="#" id="imgscr" alt="Alternate Text" />
```